# relationship item / typology Laravel 7

Tags: database-design, relationship

I am making a crud app with Laravel 7.

I am able to create items with a name and 2 image files (uploaded from the browser in a form).

I am able to edit/delete each item.

now I want to create a typologies table with 2 typologies, each with a name and an image (that I already stored in storage/public/app, etc, they work I was able to show them in browser with asset{{}}).

Every Item I create Must have 1 of those 2 typologies.

2 questions:

- what kind of relationship is it? 1 to 1, 1 to many, or many to many?
- is there a specific guide you can recommend that you know of?

Comment: A typology can be assigned to multiple items, then.

Comment: yes i can create all the items i want and choose between these 2 typologies

should it be a many to many then? ill have to create a items_typologies table

Comment: Each item can only have 1, so, no.